# How to use ternary operator in visual force page

Tags: visualforce

Can any one help me out ?Explain on ternary operator and how to use ternary operator in visual force page.Any Example .Any suggestion .Plz

Comment: Could you get more information for your question? At the moment it is not clear what is the problem you are facing.

Comment: where exactly you want to use this ? in any specific attribute or in javascript ?

Answer (score 13):

I think there is no use case in Visualforce where it could be possible to use a ternary operator (at least all my attempts returned `Error: Syntax error`).

What you may want to use is an [IF Function](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&language=en_US#IF):

```
IF(logical_test, value_if_true, value_if_false)
```

Example:

```
{!IF(someVariable == 'OK', 'it is ok', 'not ok')}
```

Comment: I'd go so far as to say that the IF statement *is* a ternary operator, as it always requires three parameters, and the two branches must return compatible data types in at least most cases, making it identical in behavior with only a 4 character "penalty" over a ?: operator.